# Como limitar o tamanho de um campo de string em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

Tenho um campo `string` de endereço no código que recebe um dado de 60 caracteres.

O que desejo é delimitar o tamanho do endereço para que só receba 30 caracteres e não acima disso, mesmo que trunque a informação.

É possível?

Comment: Está usando o que? Windows Forms, WPF, etc?

Comment: tenta pesquisa sobre o MaxLeng

Comment: Estou utilizando WindowsForms com c#

Comment: Isso varia se estiver usando WinForms, WPF ou MVC, por exemplo. Também varia se você pretende cortar um pedaço da informação ou avisar ao usuário que limite de caracteres estourou.

Comment: Na realidade eu estou gerando um arquivo txt onde  as colunas deven ser fixas. Assim sendo se eu delimitar o campo, seja o tamanho que vier do BD, ele carregará os dados , mesmo truncado, visto que as colunas tem que estar fixas.

Answer (score 5):

Provavelmente você quer algo que trunque a mensagem.

```
const int MaxTamanhoEndereco = 30;

var endereco = "Rua dos Bobos, número Zero";
if (endereco .Length > MaxTamanhoEndereco )
    endereco = endereco .Substring(0, MaxTamanhoEndereco );
```

Comment: Rodrigo, posso trabalhar com a constante como se fosse uma variavel no decorrer do código? tipo  const int testeID = 1;
                string testeID =Convert.ToString(item.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());

Comment: Para usar a constante como variável, ela não vai poder ser constante, mas pode utilizar uma variável para limitar o tamanho máximo da string.

Comment: nâo entendi... desculpe..

Comment: Quando você declara algo como constante, não pode mudar o valor mais e por isso não é possível usar como variável. No exemplo que você passou, cria duas variáveis com o mesmo nome, também daria problema.

Comment: então a única forma de delimitar a variavel por exemplo endereço é com const, isto é, eu quero que esta variavel string endereço só receba 20 caracteres até o final do processamento? Ou melhor, quero que ela seja de tamanho fixo de 20 até o final do processamento.

Comment: não, você pode usar uma variável... só não usar o const na frente.

Answer (score 3):

Se você só quer limitar um campo que vem de alguma fonte de dados para 30 caracteres, é possível usar o método [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) de `string`. Este método recebe dois parâmetros do tipo `int`.

O primeiro define qual a **posição** do primeiro caractere que deverá ser "recortado" (lembre-se que as posições começam a contar do zero), o segundo parâmetro é a **quantidade** de caracteres que devem ser "recortados".

Veja um exemplo:

```
var enderecoCompleto = db.BuscarEnderecoCliente(); //endereço vindo do banco

string endereco = enderecoCompleto.Length > 30 
                      ? enderecoCompleto.Substring(0, 30) //comece no caracter 0 e pegue 30 caracteres
                      : enderecoDoBanco;
```

Comment: Então jbueno, mas os dados veem diretamente do Banco através de uma consulta...

Comment: Ah, não tinha lido toda a pergunta, minha culpa. Tem algum problema em usar a última opção?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta pra se encaixar melhor na sua pergunta, volto em alguns minutos.

Comment: na realidade o que quero é deixar fixo o campo. me parece que deixando como o Rodrigo informou seria o ideal...   "const int MaxTamanhoEndereco = 30";

Comment: então a única forma de delimitar a variavel por exemplo endereço  é com const, isto é, eu quero que esta variavel string endereço   só receba  20 caracteres até o final do  processamento? Ou melhor, quero que ela seja de tamanho fixo de 20 até o final do  processamento.

Comment: @JoeliasAndrade Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi fazer uma opção mais sofisticada do que já foi respondido. Dá para melhorar mais adotando alguns critérios mais bem definidos.

Não pensei na eficiência, tem alocações desnecessárias neste código e dá para melhorar isto, mas algumas é um pouco complicado sem ter que refazer muita coisa pronta porque a biblioteca não ajuda ser eficiente.

Adotei o critério que deve colocar `...` por padrão para indicar que o texto foi capado, e isto é muito importante do ponto de vista de usabilidade.

Também adotei que uma palavra não poderia ser cortada, ou mostra toda ela ou nada. Também considerei que se a primeira palavra é grande demais pode cortar no meio.

Na maioria das situações, isto seria o desejado.

```
using static System.Console;

const int MaxTamanhoEndereco = 30;
WriteLine(TrimPosition("AvenidaAventureirosAfortunados, 1234", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition("Rua Aventureiros Afortunados, 12345", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition("Av Aventureiros Afortunados, 12345", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition("R Aventureiros Afortunados, 12345", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition(" Aventureiros Afortunados, 12345", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition("Aventureiros Afortunados, 12345", MaxTamanhoEndereco));
WriteLine(TrimPosition("Aventureiros Afortunados, 1234", MaxTamanhoEndereco));

static string TrimPosition(string text, int limit, string specialChars = " ,.", string trimMarker = "...") {
    if (text.Length > limit) {
        var markerLength = trimMarker.Length;
        var isSpecial = specialChars.Contains(text.Substring(limit - markerLength, 1));
        text = text.Substring(0, limit - markerLength);
        var posicaoUltimoEspaco = text.LastIndexOfAny(specialChars.ToCharArray());
        text = ((posicaoUltimoEspaco > 0 && !isSpecial) ? text.Substring(0, posicaoUltimoEspaco) : text) + trimMarker;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mN2eQk). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fd4TH8). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/TrimPosition.cs).